# how to convert Excel file to XML

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I got requirement to convert excel file, that hold about 1000 records into XML file, where XML tags and structure are different than excel records header.

Any quick solution for that ???

Many Thanks

Comment: I had this once, but why I did was kind of stupid.
excel to a database, and then exported the DB as XML file.

Comment: i guess this will do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Check if this site helps if you wish to convert it online

http://www.zamzar.com/

You can also save the excel with saveas option as XML spreadsheet 2003

After saving it as an xml you can write a xslt to get your desired XML structure.

Comment: i need with different tags than from excel records heading